# CocoaPods already installed but display error message not installed once more

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I'm a new in flutter, I bought a new MacBook Pro BigSur and I try to install flutter.
I have a problem with CocoaPods, I did evrything and finally I successfully installed as you can see in my flutter doctor. But the problem now, when I running the simulator, I get the same message error, CocoaPods not installed or invalid state.... I don't understand this situation and how must I do now ?

please help me ....

here my flutter doctor ..

````
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 11.6.2 20G314 darwin-x64, locale
    en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[!] Android Studio
    ✗ Android Studio not found at
      /Applications/android-studio-2021.1.1.20-mac.dmg/Contents
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories. ```


Error message : 

``` Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.```


successfully installation message : 

``` Fetching cocoapods-1.11.2.gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.11.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.11.2
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 2 seconds
1 gem installed. ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin:$PATH"`

Setting the path to the latest version of Ruby & then opening the Application directly from cmd line/terminal fixed it for me.

`open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

Answer (score 1):

Try: **sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi**
And then run: **arch -x86_64 pod install**

You would also need to update your podfile in the iOS folder, uncomment the second line and replace '9.0' with '10.0'

It should work.

Comment: [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
but I have a Podfile....

Comment: I'm facing the issue, it seems that Android Studio is not detecting where CocoaPods is installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Android Studio, this is an issue that users have been getting with the new "Bumblebee" release 2021.1.1 that just came out.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97251

Workaround for now is to launch Android Studio using the command line like this:

```
open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

Comment: after a many solutions, this is the only one working for me. thank you